# palace label on top to its control with boostrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

the labels inside the last  are placed to the left instead of to

the top, as the others labels are placed.
What's wrong in my  markup in order to get that result (label on top)

here an image of what i'd like to achieve
http://www.filedropper.com/bootstrap

my current markup is this:

```
<form id="PoiEditorForm" role="form" name="PoiEditorForm" novalidate>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="PoiName">Name</label>
            <input id="PoiName" type="text" ng-model="vm.poi.name" class="form-control" 

placeholder="Insert name here" required />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="PoiDescription">Description</label>
            <textarea id="PoiDescription" ng-model="vm.poi.description" class="form-

control" rows="3" placeholder="Insert description here" required></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="PoiLocation">Location</label>
            <input id="PoiLocation" type="text" ng-model="vm.poi.location" class="form-

control" placeholder="Insert location here" required />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-inline">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="PoiLat">Lat:</label><input type="text" id="PoiLat" ng-

model="vm.poi.lat" class="form-control" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="PoiLng">Lng:</label><input type="text" id="PoiLng" ng-

model="vm.poi.lng" class="form-control" />
                </div>
            </div>
       </div>
       <button ng-click="vm.savePoi()" ng-disabled="PoiEditorForm.$invalid" type="submit" 

class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
</form>
```

Comment: The link you've posted doesn't show an image.

Comment: on that page there is a download button (download the image)

Comment: Honestly, I would recommend against posting a link to download anything. Just post the image or a link to the image itself.